# Find one solution of equation via sympy solve()

Tags: sympy, equation, solver, parametric-equations

Is there a way to find one solution of a complicated equation via sympy. It seems finding all the solutions is too sophisticated.

I have tried to put quik = True but it does not improve the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If the equation is a polynomial you can request a particular `RootOf` solution; if it is a univariate expression you can get a numerical solution "near some intial guess" with `nsolve`.